# Is this a good solution to handle NHibernate Isession as PerWebRequest

Tags: nhibernate, session, castle-windsor

I Have been struggeling with NHibernate session management and have now ended up with two possible solutions to meet a session per web request.

I'm using Windsor for IoC in an ASPNET mvc project

First solution is to open a session in begin_request and close/dispose it again in end_request. In Windsor setup I would have
container.Register(Component.For().UsingFactoryMethod(() => SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession()).LifeStyle.Transient;

This solution creates the session per request and shares it through GetCurrentSession.

The second solution is to use Windsor like

container.Register(Component.For().UsingFactoryMethod(() => SessionFactory.OpenSession()).LifeStyle.PerWebRequest);

This sould also give me an session per web request and support constructor injection. It's a bit more simpel, but I need a second opinion.

Please let me know what you would prefer to use,

best regards
Rasmus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a unit of work, which I configure per web request in the container. The unit of work does not just create a session, but it also commits and rolls back transactions. The main reason to use a unit of work is to make the database more stable. More information about the unit of work pattern can be found on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981865/the-unit-of-work-pattern-within-a-asp-net-mvc-application/1982219#1982219).

```
public interface INHiberanteUnitOfWork
{
    ISession session { get; }
    void Commit();
    void RollBack();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't recommend any of those two solutions. Instead of trying to reinvent the wheel, use the [NHibernate facility](http://www.castleproject.org/container/facilities/trunk/nhibernate/index.html).

Comment: What kind of wheel is going to be reinvented here?

Comment: @Paco: NHibernate session management with Windsor in a web application

Comment: Wrapping any sort of IUoW pattern with your own, and programming against that will save you immense amount of refactoring when you decide to change persistance technology. It is maybe 10 minutes to write the wrapper, no extra time during development, and abstracts away from interfaces you dont control. It might sound a bit paranoic, but once you experience the hassle with changing persistence providers, you will not think about it twice any more.