# Unit of Work Method with Lazy Loading concerns, nHibernate, ASP.NET MVC, Castle Windsor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, castle-windsor, lazy-loading

Given a rather simple structure in C#...

```
class Member
{
 virtual string Email { get; set; }
 virtual IList<Character> Characters { get; set; }
}

class Character
{
 virtual string Name { get; set; }
}

interface IMemberRepository
{
 MemberCreateStatus CreateMember(string email, string password);
 bool ValidateMember(string email, string password);
 Member RetrieveMember(string email);
 void SaveMember(Member member);
}

interface ICharacterRepository
{
 Character CreateCharacter(string name);
}


class MemberRepository : IMemberRepository
{
 private readonly ISessionFactory sessionFactory;

 public MemberRepository(ISessionFactory sessionFactory)
 {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
 }

 // 
 public Member RetrieveMember(string email)
 {
    using(var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
    {
      return // member retrieval query
    }
 }
}
```

I have an ASP.NET MVC Application set up to use nHibernate (fluent configuration) and Castle.Windsor for IoC. This works fine and good, but herein lies the problem.

### Lazy Loading

By default nature, `IList<Character>` is lazy loaded in most any ORM (nHibernate, Entity Framework, etc) - Now this is not a bad thing, but I have run into a lot of confusion about how to approach this scenario.

- I want to add a `Character` to a `Member`. Logically, I would use `Member.Characters.Add(n);` and then call `MemberRepository.SaveMember(m);`

This is now problem because of the **Unit of Work** concept. I am supposed to create a `Session`, do the work, and then destroy it after returning the results. That works fine ,but now I have the following object...

`Member`

- nHibernate Lazy Loaded Proxy ( `IList<Character>` )
- `Email`

So then, I call `var member = memberRepository.RetrieveMember(email);` in my `Controller`, then I call `member.Characters.Add(character);` And here is where the mess comes in.

> The collection does not exist because it is lazy loaded, and the `Session` has been disposed.

So then, what is the answer? Sure, I could set my `IList<Character>` to not Lazy Load, but that's just kind of stupid. One of the biggest ORM libraries in the world wouldn't be using lazy loading if impeded the basic design structure. How does this concept of *UnitOfWork* play into the `IRepository<T>` pattern of `IoC` and Injection Dependency?

My first thought was to just abstract the task to the Repository, and include an `AddCharacter(Character character)` method to the `IMemberRepository`, but I've now been told that is 'not what repositories are intended for'. So I'm not quite sure what to do from this point forward. Programatically I know many solutions, but I need to understand what the **right** solution is to keep with the standards.

nHibernate's `Session` class has a method named `Persist(object obj)` that I have made work with a *UnitOfWork* pattern - but from what I can tell, this method removes the Lazy Loading aspect of whatever it is applied to. If that were a by-call basis, it would be fine - but I'm of the understanding I cannot do that. I cannot talk to my `Session` directly - only my `Repository` classes are supposed to be allowed to communicate with the `SessionFactory`. So I'm really pulling my hair out in confusion, now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass the ISession into the respository class constructor. The session-per-request pattern is usually used in a web application so that the lifetime of the ISession is the same as the HTTP request. In my opinion, repository classes should never access the SessionFactory and should always have the ISession supplied as a dependency.

Comment: So, how would I set that up using a `UnitOfWork(ISessionFactory)` and Castle.Windsor with my various Controllers? What *should* be getting the `ISessionFactory`? Do I want that in my Controller? I can't instantiate a `UnitOfWork` with a parameterless constructor... I'm not really understanding how this would work with Windsor.

Comment: I don't know how to make that work with Windsor. The ISessionFactory should be initialized when the application starts. The ISession should be created on every request. This search should point you in the right direction: http://www.google.com/search?q=windsor+nhibernate+session-per-request

Comment: Sorry.. that isn't of much help.

Comment: ? The 5th link in the search results directly addresses your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276408/is-this-a-good-solution-to-handle-nhibernate-isession-as-perwebrequest

Comment: Actually, this does help a bit more. I know what I need to more specifically ask, now. I think this resolves this specific problem, but opens up a new one. I'll give credit where it is due, and make a new question for the new problem. Thank you for your help.